# Counting letters in a string with python

Tags: python, string

I've got the following exercise: *Write the function countA(word) that takes in a word as argument and returns the number of 'a' in that word.* Examples

```
>>> countA("apple")
1
>>> countA("Apple")
0
>>> countA("Banana")
3
```

My solution is:

```
def countA(word):
  return len([1 for x in word if x is 'a'])
```

And it's ok. But I'm not sure if it's the best pythonic way to solve this, since I create a list of `1` values and check its length. Can anyone suggest something more pythonic?

Comment: `word.count('a')`?

Comment: your list comprehension is a common pattern used in python. Ther's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Volatility yep, that's a lot better than what I've written. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: it seems more like a C exercise :-P

Comment: @Ant well, yep, it's strange. I found it at pyschools.com. There are some more exercses like that, but it's also a way to remind all most important python methods ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
def countA(word):
    return word.count('a')
```

As another example, `myString.count('c')` will return the number of occurrences of c in the string

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're not just allowed to use `word.count()` - here's another way - possibly faster than summing a generator and enables you to do multiple letters if you wanted...

```
def CountA(word):
    return len(word) - len(word.translate(None, 'A'))
```

Or:

```
def CountA(word):
    return len(word) - len(word.replace('A', ''))
```

Answer (score 3):

In python, strings are sequences (just like a list).

Then you could use [count](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) :

```
>>> 'Apple'.count('p')
2
```

Using this, the answer to your exercise would be:

```
def countA(word):
    return word.count('a')
```

Comment: You mean "a sequence" not "iterable". True, both strings and lists are iterable (as are all sequences) but being iterable has nothing to with `count` or the rest of this answer.

Comment: @Jon-Eric Edited consequently.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered, but I can't believe nobody mentioned using a Counter for this, since it's very well suited to this problem. It might have a little more overhead, but if you want to find multiple letters it's probably the best way to go. Here it is in a simple, readable lambda function.

```
from collections import Counter

count = lambda word, letter: Counter(word)[letter]

count("test", "t")
>>> 2
```

Comment: +1, but note that `Counter(word).get(letter, 0)` can be replaced with `Counter(word)[letter]` as `Counter` returns 0 for missing items

Comment: @1_CR Oh huh, totally forgot about that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> def countA(word):
  return sum(1 for x in word if x == 'a')

>>> countA("apple")
1
>>> countA("Apple")
0
>>> countA("Banana")
3
```

Comment: `sum` and `length` return the same, as long as `1` is returned inside the list comprehension.

Comment: thats basically the same as what he did

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz You construct redundant list with `[1 for x in word if x is 'a']` and then calculate its length. `Sum` on the other hand just goes trough iterator over the original word.

Comment: @Stephan Not exactly. And this looks like a home assignment. So I don't think `word.count` is expected.

Comment: Don't use `is 'a'` use `== a`

Comment: @JonClements why is `==` better here than `is` (in this case)?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz `is` is incorrect. It returned correct results only accidentally (because in Python small equal strings point to the same objects, but for longer equal strings objects will be different, so `is` will return False).